# Installing Windows 8.1 upgrade gives the error 0x80070057

Tags: windows-installation, windows-store, windows-8.1-upgrade

I'm running Windows 8 and attempting to install Windows 8.1 via the app store. I attempted this several times and each time I get a message that the install failed with error message 0x80070057.

Searching didn't turn up any meaningful solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Temporarily Disable Anti-Virus

This error occurs when you attempt to install the 8.1 update with some type of Anti-Virus solution enabled. Users of Microsoft's Security Essentials also need to disable the realtime protection before attempting the 8.1 upgrade.

There are other users [reporting](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Windows-8-1-Installation-Error-0x80070057-392252.shtml) that the same thing happens with different AV solutions.

### Clearing Windows Store Cache

[Sometimes](http://www.eightforums.com/windows-8-news/33101-windows-8-1-installation-error-0x80070057-2.html) this issue can occur from an issue in the Windows Store Cache.

To [clear the cahce](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13133-store-cache-clear-windows-8-a.html), on your keyboard hit <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `WSReset.exe`.

Comment: Um, Microsoft Security Essentials does not support Windows 8.

Comment: You are correct, MSE was renamed Windows Defender. http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/windows8.aspx#antivirus